# Error url with parameters (read key from web.config) mvc c# visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, url, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013, web-config

I have the following code :

```
public ActionResult Signin()
{
    var state = Guid.NewGuid(); // work for application state if required then we can use it.
    var oAuthUrl = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorizationEndpoint"]}?response_type=code&redirect_uri={ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"]}&client_id={ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"]}&env={ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"]}&state={state}";
    return Redirect(oAuthUrl);
}
```

there is a error in syntax of oAuthUrl. Please, i need your help

Comment: So you store information about sites that use your site as OAuth in `web.config`? It's not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you might need to install NuGet package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager. What is the .Net version you are targetting?
I am asking it here since my reputation is not enough to comment on the original question.

```
public ActionResult Signin()
        {
            var state = Guid.NewGuid(); // work for application state if required then we can use it.
            var oAuthUrl = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorizationEndpoint"]}?response_type=code&redirect_uri={ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"]}&client_id={ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"]}&env={ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"]}&state={state}";
            return Redirect(oAuthUrl);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I am using Net.Framework 4.5.1

Comment: I have created Web API targeting the .Net Framework 4.5.1. There is no syntax error. Also the redirect works fine. I have updated my answer with code.